# How to wait for thread to finish execution?

Tags: c, winapi, thread-safety, waitforsingleobject

Is there a way to check if the child process created with `CreateThread` has finished execution

This code does print the output of the command but only when a proper wait time is added to `WaitForSingleObject` in this case 5 seconds is enough but this is not always the case

```
#define BUFSIZE 4096


HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE handle = NULL;



DWORD grab_output(void * args)
{   
   DWORD dwRead, total=0; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   for (;;) 
   { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if( ! bSuccess ) break;
        printf("%s", chBuf);

    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int run()
{
    BOOL res; 
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    
    DWORD n_size; 
    
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa, 0)) 
        return GetLastError();
    
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        return GetLastError();

    memset(&si, 0 ,sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);
    si.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr; 
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if(!CreateProcess(NULL,              
                        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c ping google.com",    
                        NULL,    
                        NULL,   
                        TRUE,         
                        CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
                        NULL,
                        NULL,                              
                        &si,              
                        &pi                 
                        ))
                        {
    }
    else
    {
        handle = CreateThread(0, 0, grab_output, NULL, 0, NULL);
        WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    run();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using `GetExitCodeThread` in the run function but it does not seem to work properly and keeps outputting the same exit code before and after the child has finished execution, I also tried using `WaitForSingleObject` and I checked the return code but it too keeps outputting `WAIT_TIMEOUT`

the output

```
$ gcc temp2.c && ./a.exe 

Pinging google.com [172.217.168.238] with 32 bytes of data:
2.217.168.238] Reply from 172.217.168.238: 7.168.238] bytes=32 time=87ms TTL=57
 7.168.238] Reply from 172.217.168.238: 7.168.238] bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=57
 7.168.238] Reply from 172.217.168.238: 7.168.238] bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=57
 7.168.238] Reply from 172.217.168.238: 7.168.238] bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=57

Ping statistics for 172.217.168.238:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 86ms, Maximum = 96ms, Average = 88ms
```

this never seems to return back the console because of `INFINITE`

How do I properly check if the child process has finished execution

Comment: A call to `WaitForSingleObject` with a timeout value of `INFINITE` will not return `WAIT_TIMEOUT`. Though that's a moot point since the sequence of `CreateThread` immediately followed by `WaitForSingleObject` is just a very costly way to implement a single-threaded program.

Comment: Also, you don't need this mess just to send a ping, use [`IcmpSendEcho2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho2) like a regular human being!

Comment: @Blindy what if i wanted to use another command

Comment: @IInspectable could you please recommend what should i do in this case

Comment: Same answer, learn your API.

Comment: @Blindy I am doing exactly that this is why I am asking how to do such task and i don't see how [`IcmpSendEcho2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho2) could help me in such task

Comment: In this case you should update your question to include the behavior that's actually observed.

Comment: @IInspectable please check the updated question

Comment: @Blindy I know how to use `ping` I would have used it with out creating a program with `ping` hardcoded in it, my goal is to take user input and run it as a command

Comment: Your updated question still doesn't describe the observed behavior. See my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire code and explanation make literally no sense.

> the child process created with CreateThread

`CreateThread` doesn't create processes, this isn't Linux.

```
   if(!CreateProcess(NULL,              
                    "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c ping google.com",    
                    NULL,    
                    NULL,   
                    TRUE,         
                    CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
                    NULL,
                    NULL,                              
                    &si,              
                    &pi                 
                    ))
                    {
```

You create a process and don't store it's handle anywhere, what is your thinking here?

> I tried using GetExitCodeThread in the run function but it does not seem to work properly

Blaming your tools because you use them wrong peg your skill level as a programmer very appropriately. <strike>How can you even check the exit code if you don't store the process handle anywhere?</strike>

> I also tried using WaitForSingleObject

Not on your process you didn't, you used it on some random thread you felt like creating for no reason.

In short, if you insist on doing things the wrong, brittle, inefficient and un-portable way, store your process handle and use `WaitForSingleObject` on it. If you want to wait until it's over (ie freeze your application until then, which is in line with the rest of your code), use an `INFINITE` parameter. If you want to simply check if it's done, use `0`.

Otherwise, use [`IcmpSendEcho2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho2) like I said.

Comment: *"You create a process and don't store it's handle anywhere"* - The process handle is stored in the [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information) structure `pi` that's filled out by the `CreateProcess` call.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that and corrected my response. Doesn't change the fact that he's not using it.

Comment: I am no expert programmer and the windows docs seem overwhelming for a beginner

Comment: Then ask about it. It's a much better comment than, and I quote, "i don't see how IcmpSendEcho2 could help me in such task". Though in this particular case it's trivial, create the file, send the echo request and inspect the result. Bam, done!

Comment: Pretending that the child process is doing something more substantial than a ping, waiting for the worker thread is correct, and waiting for the child process would be wrong.  There can still be unprocessed data in the pipe at the moment the process exits; you need to give the helper thread time to process it.

Answer (score 1):

Blindy's concerns are valid if you intend to wait for the process to exit.  If you instead intend to wait until your thread reads all output from the process (and you should), the fix is much simpler.

In this loop, you failed to account for the "end of file" condition:

```
for (;;) 
{ 
   bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
   if( ! bSuccess ) break;
   printf("%s", chBuf);
}
```

End-of-file is indicated by a **successful** read with zero length.

You also call printf on data that isn't NUL-terminated.

Fixing both those issues:

```
for (;;) { 
   bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
   if (!bSuccess) break;
   if (dwRead == 0) break;
   fwrite(chBuf, 1, dwRead, stdout);
}
```

Now, when the child process exits, it will close its pipe handle.  Your reading thread will read an end-of-file and exit its loop, but only after printing all the data it read from the pipe.  Returning from your thread procedure will wake the `WaitForSingleObject` waiting on the thread.

Following Blindy's advice would exit your program too early, without the "only after printing all the data it read from the pipe" behavior.

However, Blindy is right that you didn't have any particular reason to create that thread.  You could just call `grab_output(nullptr)` instead.  With the above fixes, that will work perfectly.